# Ionic 3 - Angular Post with headers not working

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular5

Using Ionic 3 with angular 5.2.11.

Angular Post with headers not working

```
....
const header = {
        "headers": {
          "X-Custom-Header": "1",
          "X-Custom-Header2": "2"
        }
      };
...
const dt = {
  Username: this.username,
  Password: this.password
}
this.data = this.http.post('http://mydomain/json.php?f=test', JSON.stringify(dt), header);
this.data.subscribe(data => {
  this.testPass.push(data);
}, (error) => {
  this.testPass.push(error);
});
```

PHP backend:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

if ($_GET["f"] == "test") {
    echo 1;
    die();
}
```

Without a header, this call is working. My purpose is to pass the headers. Then it stacks and the weirdest is that I don't get any error.
Any thoughts to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in PHP:

This line is not accepted for Android below 8 and for custom headers:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

I had to put my values manually:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding, X-Custom-Header, X-Custom-Header2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const header = {
   "X-Custom-Header": "1",
   "X-Custom-Header2": "2"
}

const requestOptions = {                                                                                                                                                                                 
     headers: new Headers(header), 
};

getData() {
  return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), requestOptions);
}
```

Call from component:

```
this.yourServiceFile.getData().subscribe(res => {console.log(res); });
```

Another Way:

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('X-Custom-Header', '1');
headers = headers.append('X-Custom-Header2', '2');
```

and pass the `headers` to your request.

Comment: In the first option I get: Argument of type ... is not assignable to parameter of type 'HeadersInit'. Property '"headers"' is incompatible with index signature. Type header is not assignable to type 'string'.
In the second option I got: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'HttpHeaders' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | ....